# Default timezone for a recurring job on HangFire

Tags: .net, timezone, hangfire, cron-task

Does anyone know the default timezone used by Hangfire when setting up a recurring job? I suspect it is UTC and not the timezone of the host server.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect the *real* question is how to specify the timezone, not whether it's UTC or local.

The [Cron class docs](https://api.hangfire.io/html/T_Hangfire_Cron.htm) explicitly specify that UTC is used, eg:

> Daily() Returns cron expression that fires every day at 00:00 UTC.
>
> Daily(Int32)   Returns cron expression that fires every day at the first minute of the specified hour in UTC.

etc

That's just the default though. The `Cron` class doesn't *hard-code* the timezone, it simply creates a CRON string. If you want to use a different timezone you can pass it through the `timeZone` parameter in [all AddOrUpdate](https://api.hangfire.io/html/Overload_Hangfire_RecurringJob_AddOrUpdate.htm) overloads.

The parameter accepts a [TimeZoneInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo?view=netframework-4.8) instance. TimeZoneInfo allows you to specify a timezone by its Windows name, UTC or `Local`, in which case it returns the system's timezone.

In that case though the problem becomes `What's the server's timezone?` If the web app needs to use a specific timezone it's better to be explicit, especially when using cloud VMs

Comment: UTC is the answer I was looking for. The question was simple about the whether the default timezone local or UTC. How to set the timezone is very clear in the HangFire documentation and API itself. Thanks you for your help.